# How do I check which changeset my workspace is in

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs, source-control-explorer

In Team foundation server, In order to analyze a bug that is currently in production, I used the "get latest version" functionality to get the changeset that was active in production so that I could run my unit tests against it.

I want to double-check which changeset I got just to make sure that I actually did get the correct version of source code.

Is there an easy way to do this with tfs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bring up the file/folder in Source Control Explorer, right-click and go to Properties it will show you the latest version on the server and your workspace version.

[image]

Comment: In VS 2017 this method shows a *different* (as in much older) changeset than the correct answer given [by this `tf history` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7760096/2375855). Any idea why?