# On what change-set is my local working copy?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I want to be able to see (in VS2013 UI) till which change-set I updated my files.

The reason I ask this is because of the following scenario:
I created a fix, checked it in and continued working on something else. One day later, my colleague is testing the bug I solved but found it unsolved. Next, I tried to reproduce it at my machine but was not able to do so. So I wondered whether my colleague got the latest version before starting to test, he was convinced he did, but we cannot find a way to see on what change-set he is.

It is important for us to know this information without getting the latest version and retest it. Since the testing procedure for this bug takes quite some time, and time is valuable.

I'm quite new to TFS and we just switched from SVN to TFS. At SVN, using tortoise, the revision of the local working copy was highlighted, so the user knew which revisions he missed or was at.
I would like to be able to get this same information via VS2013.

I searched the web and found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748039/get-current-changeset-id-on-workspace-for-tfs) but it uses the command line and I want to see it in the UI. Beside that, I couldn't get the command to work.

The question: Where can I find the number of the change-set in the VS2013 user-interface, my local working copy is on?

Comment: Your best option to find the workspace version is to [use the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7760096/56793).  Open a Developer Command Prompt and use the `tf` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One place I know of is in the source control explorer window of Visual Studio.

1: right click a file and go to Advanced->Properties
2: Under the general tab you will see "Workspace Version #" and "Latest Version #"

Comment: To bad I have to do that per file =/... Seems like the only option though. I wait for a day or so, if there won't be any other (better) answers I'll accept yours.

Comment: That only gives the version of that particular file.  It's completely impractical to use this to find the actual workspace version.

Answer (score 0):

In the Source Code Explorer you should have a column for "latest". This will tell you at a glance if you have the latest or not.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. It is not recursive, so it only works per  file/folder and only tells 'yes' or 'no' whether it is so.