# How to programatically get version of local copy

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs

Is there a way to find out version (changesetid) of local file (workspace version)?

In visual studio I can compare file with workspace version so there must be a way to find out what is current workspace version.

Comment: tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W Dupelicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748039/get-current-changeset-id-on-workspace-for-tfs

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that come to mind
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.getlocalversions(v=vs.120).aspx

And
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh723884(v=vs.120).aspx

The former gives you only version and is super fast. The latter returns much more info. They are else exposed through cmd, tf localversions and tf items i think