# Local version of tfs solution

Tags: tfs, version-control

I have a solution that is under tfs version control. How can I find out what the current version of the solution on my local computer (what the latest changeset my solution includes)?

Comment: Found the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748039/get-current-changeset-id-on-workspace-for-tfs). Just use history command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf history command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/tfvc/history-command) which displays the revision history of one or more files or folders. This command can be invoked through the Developer Command Prompt for VS20XX installed together with Visual Studio.

```
tf hist[ory] itemspec [/version:versionspec] 
[/stopafter:number] [/recursive] [/user:username] 
[/format:(brief|detailed)] [/slotmode] [/itemmode] [/noprompt]
[/login:username,[password]] [/sort:ascending,descending]
[/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```